# Calculus function create

Tags: calculus, special-functions

Create an example of a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(f(f(\mathbb{R}))) = f(f(\mathbb{R})) \neq f(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Comment: This is one of my homework questions, the name of course is Mathematical Proofs. And I really don't understand how I supposed to create such a function. I know it supposed to be a piecewise function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of functions work.
Figure out what the conditions imply. Try to modify when you get stuck.
This is a good question to play around with, so I don't want you to just see the answer. (But, given how this site works, just saying this will lead to negative comments, so I gave an explicit construction  hidden below)

> $f (x)  = \begin{cases} 0 & x \text{ rational} \\ 1 & x \text{ irrational} \end{cases} $

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99485/discussion-on-answer-by-calvin-lin-calculus-function-create).